# Is correct summarizing 2 times in a row in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data with the states, month and year when people die. I need to calculate the median of the number of people died in each month (across years).

So, the first step is to calculate the number of people died by month and year:

```
data %>% group_by(state, month, year) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

```r
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             State = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y"),
             Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
              Year = c(2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L),
                 n = c(20L, 15L, 45L, 54L)
)
```

at this point, I have a dataframe like this (these numbers are just an example):

| State | Month | Year | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2019 | 20 |
| X | 1 | 2020 | 15 |
| Y | 1 | 2019 | 45 |
| Y | 1 | 2020 | 54 |

But I want to calculate the median, so I write

```
data %>% group_by(state, month, year) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% summarise(median = median(n))
```

| State | Month | median |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 17.5 |
| Y | 1 | 49.5 |

I obtain my desired result, but i don't know if R is making some things from behind that I don't see.

My question is: It is something bad to 'summarise()' twice in a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `first` summarise, by default the last grouping is dropped i.e.  year.  So, the second summarise is based on the 'State' and 'Month' (if that it is the OP's desired outcome).  In this case, two `summarise` makes sense.  It may be better to specify the `.groups` option to make sure that what we need i.e. `drop_last` will drop the last group and in the second `summarise`, remove the grouping with `drop`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(state, month, year) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop_last') %>%
  summarise(median = median(n), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That was i was thinking. But I have 1 question now; why put as an argument ``` .groups = 'drop' ```? It's like irrelavant, or it matters?

Comment: @scalamardo it doesn't really matter as by default, it does remove the last grouping variable in that order.  But, it may also print a warning message depending on the dplyr version.  By specifying the `.groups`, that warning will be gone.